# Equivalent subshifts

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, combinatorics-on-words

Let $X$ be a finite set, $(X^{\mathbb Z}, T)$ is the shift, i.e. the Tikhonov topological space of all bi-infinite words in $X$, $T$ shifts the words one letter to the right. A subshift is a closed subset of $X^{\mathbb{Z}}$ stable under $T$.
 Is there a recent survey about the problem of equivalence of subshifts?

Comment: In what sense "equivalencve"? There are several notions ranging from conjugacy to orbit equivalence.

Comment: @SIB: In all possible senses. I know of some versions and would like, in particular, to know about the others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The paper *[Open Problems in Symbolic Dynamics](http://www-users.math.umd.edu/~mmb/open/)* by Mike Boyle discusses the conjugacy problem for shifts of finite type and sofic shifts.

More details can be found in books such as *[An Introduction to Symbolic Dynamics
and Coding](http://www.math.washington.edu/SymbolicDynamics/)*.